# Getting Error while springBoot start Up (Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Error while SpringBoot start Up. I am using jetty with SpringBoot excluding Tomcat

```
2018-04-10 12:00:31.703  WARN 13924 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/gzip/GzipHandler
2018-04-10 12:00:31.733  INFO 13924 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-10 12:00:31.817 ERROR 13924 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/gzip/GzipHandler
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at com.wipro.c4.partner.airline.sabre.app.main.ApplicationMain.main(ApplicationMain.java:37) [partner.airline.sabre.sbt-2.0.2.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/gzip/GzipHandler
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:170) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
```

---

Dependencies added to the POM file. There are other dependencies also which add jetty of the version 9.0.7

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This look like something that is link to the multiple jetty versions living in your project. I suggest to exclude jetty from the other dependencies that depend on jetty. If this doesn't work please post the full pom.xml for us to see all the dependencies and the versions you use.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks